# Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL (pass username and password in URL to access a file)

Tags: java

i write a program that will fetch a file specified by a URL. but my code gives me "Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL". i googled on this and found that, this error is due to authentication failure. so my question is that : how i can pass my username and password along with my URL?
here is my code

```
String login="dostix12";
String password="@@@@@";
String loginPassword = login+ ":" + password;
String encoded = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode (loginPassword.getBytes());
URL url = new URL("https://level.x10hosting.com:2083/cpsess5213137721/frontend/x10x3/filemanager/showfile.html?file=factorial.exe&fileop=&dir=%2Fhome%2Fdostix12%2Fetc&dirop=&charset=&file_charset=&baseurl=&basedir=");
url.openConnection();
```

Comment: We don't have any super powers to guess your code.Please show us the code

Comment: Have you tried any of the [default HTTP authentication mechanisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)?

Comment: yes i did.............

Answer (score 4):

It will depend on how the server is expecting the credentials. General way of accepting the authentication details is using [BASIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) authentication mechanism. In Basic authentication, you need to set the `Authroization` http header.

The Authorization header is constructed as follows:

> Username and password are combined into a string "username:password"
>
> The resulting string literal is then encoded using Base64
>
> The authorization method and a space i.e. "Basic " is then put before
>   the encoded string.
>
> For example, if the user agent uses 'Aladdin' as the username and
>   'open sesame' as the password then the header is formed as follows:

Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==

Source : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Here is a sample code to add the authorization header:

```
  url = new URL(targetURL);
  connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
  BASE64Encoder enc = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
  String userpassword = username + ":" + password;
  String encodedAuthorization = enc.encode( userpassword.getBytes() );
  connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+
        encodedAuthorization);
```

Comment: connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+
        encodedAuthorization);                                                                        what does connection means in your code

Comment: @user2606088       connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

Comment: @user2606088 in that case, you may either be using the wrond credentials or the server may be using a different authentication scheme.

Comment: String credentials = "@@@@@" + ":" + "@@@@@";  
        BASE64Encoder enc = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
        String encoding = enc.encode(credentials.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        URL url = new URL("xyz.com");
        HttpURLConnection connection =    HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", String.format("Basic %s", encoding));

Answer (score 4):

Use the following the code, it would work:

```
final URL url = new URL(urlString);
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator()
{
  @Override
  protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
  {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password.toCharArray());
  }
});
final URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the **Authorization** header in your HTTP request, in it you should send username and password encoded in base64.

more info here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_headers